# Pass Multiple Parameters in BIRT report Query

Tags: mysql, json, postgresql

I need to Pass multiple parameters to my PostGres Query in BIRT Report .

The following is my query:

```
 select
 t1.id as id, 
 t1.json->>'group_zl6oo94/group_wb1hp47/location' as   value_of_slum_location
 from logger_instance as t1 , logger_xform as t2 
 where t1.xform_id=t2.id 
 and t2.title=? 
 and cast(t1.json as text) like '%' + ? + '%';
```

I need to pass two parameter i.e Title and Text.

I have created two `data_source_properties` for each parameter and created two `report_parameters` for each.

I am not able to run the report due to this.

Please help me run this query.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz can u pls help me here....

Comment: is it a solr reports?..